# Write dataframe record count to HDFS location in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe df which have some records. I am using

```
df.write.text()
```

to write to HDFS location. 
Along with it I need to write recordcount also into HDFS location in another directory.How to do the same in spark scala?

Comment: have you tried doing df.count and saving that to another path?

Comment: how to write df.count to a HDFS location?

Comment: Not sure if this the best approach , but you could save the df.count to a variable and use FileSystem api to save the value to the hdfs file Or sc.textfile the variable.

Comment: spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(df.count),1).toDF("Count").write.save("path/to/hdfs")